# Batch file to run .exe and output to file

Tags: batch-file

I have an [.exe file](http://kb.eset.com/esetkb/index?page=content&id=SOLN333) that when run opens a cmd window that outputs a unique ID and waits for input. I have to run this .exe file on about 100 PC's to unlock their settings.

I want to run this .exe and output the ID to a text file as I don't want to have to run it manually on all machines. I have tried using a batch file but it doesn't work. What seems to be catching me is it's waiting until it receives input before it outputs to the file .

```
start "C:\unlock\Unlock.exe" >> ./Unlock.txt
cmd /K "C:\unlock\Unlock.exe" >> ./Unlock.txt
```

Attempting to feed parameters to the exe using the cmd command doesn't seem to work either.

```
cmd /k "C:\unlock\Unlock.exe" 11 >> ./Unlock.txt
```

I'm open to all suggestions for automating this. A batch file, vbs, powershell or python.
I've also tried using psexec but it does output to the cmd window I'm running the remote command from.

Comment: I can get past the initial request for input using "echo 11 | prog.exe"  or "prog.exe < inputcommands.txt" where input commnads contain input but I get over come the "Press any key to continue ..."

Comment: You may have more luck on ServerFault site

Comment: Try With `cmd /c ""C:\unlock\Unlock.exe" %Arg1% %Arg2%" >>Output.txt`